# Showing an array in home screen widget

Tags: android, arrays, widget

I am trying to show some news in the home screen and I have this code. I want to show every new after lets say 5 seconds from the array.

```
public class PointlessWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

static final String DATA_TITLE = "T";
static final String DATA_LINK  = "L";
static LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>> data1;
static String feedUrl;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    feedUrl = "http://www.blabla.com";


            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(feedUrl); 
                data1 = (LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>)parser.parse();
                                Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> itr = data1.iterator();
                Object element;
                HashMap<String, String> entry;
                String Temp_URL=null,Temp_TITULO=null,Actual_URL,Actual_TITULO,Anterior_URL = null,Anterior_TITULO,Sigiente_URL,Sigiente_TITULO;

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    element = itr.next();
                    entry = (HashMap<String, String>) element;
                    mierda = entry.get("T");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    v.setTextViewText(R.id.word_title, mierda);
                    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                    manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, v);
                    Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mierda);

                }
```

The problem is I manage to show one or two elements and then it stops because it says something like object not locked by thread before wait().

How can I implement this?
Thank you a lot

---

I implemented service but still throws ANR error.

```
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // To prevent any ANR timeouts, we perform the update in a service
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
    }

    public static class UpdateService extends Service {
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // Build the widget update for today
            RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            feedUrl = "http://www.blabla.com";


                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(feedUrl); 
                        data1 = (LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>)parser.parse();
                        int size = data1.size();
                        Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> itr = data1.iterator();
                        Object element;
                        HashMap<String, String> entry;
                        String Temp_URL=null,Temp_TITULO=null,Actual_URL,Actual_TITULO,Anterior_URL = null,Anterior_TITULO,Sigiente_URL,Sigiente_TITULO;

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                element = itr.next();
                entry = (HashMap<String, String>) element;
                mierda = entry.get("T");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                v.setTextViewText(R.id.word_title, mierda);
                ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, PointlessWidget.class);
                AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
                manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, v);
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mierda);

            }

    }
```

How can I fix this? 
Thank you!

Comment: Network work should not be on UI thread...........

Comment: Can you guid me on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will throw a Activity not responding if it's blocked for over 5 seconds [See this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html), that's probably why you can't. Use a different [thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), or asyncTask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Service to do the network stuff and parsing.

See the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) or this [example](http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/Wiktionary/src/com/example/android/wiktionary/WordWidget.java).

**EDIT:**
I think it could be a good idea using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) in this case and override `onHandleIntent()`